# Присоединительный оборот с "в частности"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Его использование будет способствовать разработке наиболее корректных Стратегий развития ТЭК и электроэнергетики, в частности не требующих частых пересмотров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно, запятой отделяется оборот вместе с вводным словом "в частности".